# Grouping & counting by two XML elements with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my input XML:

```
<root>
    <cust>
        <firstname>bob</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <age>40</age>
    </cust>
    <cust>
        <firstname>joe</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <age>75</age>
    </cust>
    <cust>
        <firstname>joe</firstname>
        <lastname>brown</lastname>
        <age>25</age>
    </cust>
    <cust>
        <firstname>pete</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <age>40</age>
    </cust>
</root>
```

Runnning it through the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="custs-by-lastname" match="cust" use="lastname"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html><body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>#</th></tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/cust[count(. | key('custs-by-lastname', lastname)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="lastname"/>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('custs-by-lastname', lastname))"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body></html>
</xsl:template>
```

will result in this output:

```
Name   #
brown  1
smith  3
```

So what the XSLT does is grouping by lastname and counting.

What I would like to achieve is this output (order unimportant):

```
Name   Age  #
smith  40   2
brown  25   1
smith  75   1
```

so grouping by lastname AND age.

I've tried to fiddle with combining lastname and age in the key-function, but I was unable to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group by name and age, then use the concatenation of name and age as the key value:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="cust" match="cust" use="concat(lastname, age)"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="cust[count(. | key('cust', concat(lastname, age))[1]) = 1]">
                    <xsl:sort select="lastname"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cust', concat(lastname, age)))"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that no name ends with a digit. Usually, a concatenated key value will include a separator (e.g. `concat(lastname, '|', age)` to prevent false matches.