# Count distinct on multiple elements with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is a follow up question to [Grouping & counting by two XML elements with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565485/grouping-counting-by-two-xml-elements-with-xslt)

This is my input XML:

```
<root>
    <cust>
        <firstname>bob</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <age>40</age>
    </cust>
    <cust>
        <firstname>joe</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <age>75</age>
    </cust>
    <cust>
        <firstname>joe</firstname>
        <lastname>brown</lastname>
        <age>25</age>
    </cust>
    <cust>
        <firstname>pete</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <age>40</age>
    </cust>
</root>
```

After processing it with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="cust" match="cust" use="concat(lastname, age)"/>
<xsl:key name="dist_cnt" match="/root/cust/lastname/text()" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="cust[count(. | key('cust', concat(lastname, age))[1]) = 1]">
                    <xsl:sort select="lastname"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cust', concat(lastname, age)))"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
            Total distinct (lastname only): <xsl:value-of select="count(/root/cust/lastname/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dist_cnt',.)[1])])"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is as follows

```
Name    Age #
brown   25  1
smith   40  2
smith   75  1

Total distinct (lastname only): 2
```

What I'm really interested in is the number 3, the number of rows of the output table.

The result "Total distinct (lastname only): 2" is just my first attempt at reaching that goal. It shows that I have managed to count the distinct number of lastname's. But I didn't get any further than that.

I'd like the result to be the total number of distinct lastname/age combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be much simpler than you're making it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="cust" match="cust" use="concat(lastname, age)"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="distinct-customers" select="cust[count(. | key('cust', concat(lastname, age))[1]) = 1]" />
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-customers">
                    <xsl:sort select="lastname"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cust', concat(lastname, age)))"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
            <xsl:text>Total distinct: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($distinct-customers)"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```